# How to formalize and validate models of fundamental factors involved price changes?

Tags: factor-models, market-model

Suppose you have some stock *X*, and its price can be considered a time series. You believe that real-world number *Y*, like industry or government statistics, which is also time series, influences stock price.

How such kinds of influences be formalized and validated? Suppose you believe that you can somehow predict *Y* ahead of time, how would you evaluate potential profit and amount of risk involved?

In regular statistics, you may consider various graphic models, including Bayesian and causation networks. But that kind of analysis usually does not involve measures of profit and risk, as far as I know. You may say that estimator analysis should be related to risk measuring, but I am not aware of how exactly that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around, I think that users of this site would probably say that *factor models* are the right formalism and these questions already cover mine:

- [How to build a factor model?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17125/how-to-build-a-factor-model)
- [How to use factor models for prediction?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31361/how-to-use-factor-models-for-prediction?noredirect=1&lq=1)

While I might specialize the question further on factor-model vs graphical model relation, overall I think it is probably not needed. So I would only close the question, not deleting it, to make it googlable if anyone would use words more closer to mine.